# Team Foundation Server 2015 Builds will not start

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I am having trouble getting my builds to run when using MSBuild in Team Foundation Server 2015. We are hosting the application on an internal server. I have configured the Controller and Agent, which seems to be okay. The "Visual Studio Team Foundation Build Service Host 2015" service is running.

[image]

When I try to queue the build, I get the following message, even though I am not using Visual Studio Online:

[image]

When I ckick OK, the build seems to be queued, but I see the following message forever:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build agent service is not start. Click **Properties** under your agent.Mark the "Build agent service is enabled"

[image]

The normal state of build control and build agent should look like as below:
[image]

Comment: For me it helped to restart the agent services

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are attempting to build a Vnext build and not a Xaml type build. You will need to set up the Vnext agent in order to get that to work. I personally use both Xaml and Vnext builds

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly it.